# Load previous session values when open new window

Tags: c#, wpf

There is a MenuItem click event **MainMenu_Define_Material** which opens a window called **Material**. I get info from a textbox called **txt_density** and I save that info in **density** and return to main window via *OK-button* having click event **Material_btn_OK_Click**.

My question is, how I can avoid passing the last session values every time I open the window **Material**?

I want, once **density** is set, every time I open **Material** window I want to see the values of previous session.

```
private void MainMenu_Define_Material(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    newWin_material = new Material();            

    newWin_material.btn_OK.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(Material_btn_OK_Click);            

    if (density != -1)
    {
        newWin_material.txt_density.Text = density.ToString();            
    }

    newWin_material.ShowDialog();
}

private void Material_btn_OK_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    density = System.Convert.ToSingle(newWin_material.txt_density.Text);    
    newWin_material.Close();            
}
```

Comment: create another ctor in `Material.xaml.cs`: `public Material(Single density){ // init controls using density  }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very clear where that `density` comes from, but you can insert that field in uour data class what you can hold on `data layer` or may be like `ObjectDataProvider` for `modelview`.

There are a lor of different solutioms our there. The basic idea is:

Define  common, shared data storage and keep there alll values you want to share between different windows.

Define a data class. I used here a `static` class with a `static` member `Desnity`.

```
public static class DataClass 
{
     public static double Desnsity;
}
```

After in any window you're able to access that field (read/write), like

```
DataClass.Density
```

Hope this is clear.

Comment: `float distance` is in main window while `txt_density` is in Material window. Is it possible to share instances like `density`. I made use of referencing classes but have never seen that for instances.

Comment: `denaity` is a field that holds some data I presume, may be `double`. So insert it into some shared data type and use a single instance of it across your app.

Comment: I think at the end, you will guide me to MVVM which I cant understand because I need examples. If you are talking about some other thing, could you provide me some examples or reference.

Comment: I don't guide you to `MVVM`, even if would like. What I'm talking about has nothing to do with `MVVM`.

Comment: Yeah, seems it works. Finally, I guess I can bind `DataClass.Density` to `txt_density`, can I?

Comment: hm.. if you're talking about `wpf-binding`, I would have some doubts on the subject, cause it's `static` and doesn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` as requested by binding mechanism. But this is naturally the implementation provided in *my* example. Improtant that you understood an idea, so you can implement your own in a way you need.

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept of Session in WPF. You can try creating a static variable to do this or a app config value or pass a parameter via the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to new it ( e.g. new Material();  ) then it is going to start with zero information.  That is what new does.  What is wrong with passing the value in the ctor?

Try

```
MainWindow 
{
    private newWin_material = new Material();    // just new it ONCE

    // this may need to be in MainWindow ctor.
    newWin_material.btn_OK.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(Material_btn_OK_Click);
```